# ElementaryOS Ubuntu Theme

Tags: unity, themes, elementary, elementary-theme

I'm trying to get the GTK theme that ElementaryOS uses working on Ubuntu 14.04 but the theme is not looking the way it should.

This is how it looks:

[image]

Rather than how it is supposed to look.

What could be the issue? Why are the Ubuntu Ambiance-style buttons still there?

Comment: Did you try rebooting afterwards?

Comment: @JeffreyLin Why, should I? Would that change anything? I assumed since the changes were instantaneous there was no need....

Comment: Try restarting, you never know what it'll fix. Also, which theme are you trying to use?

Comment: @Seth `elementary-theme` from `ppa:elementary-os/daily`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The theme is not compatible with Unity. The window borders won't work properly. Better to use a forked theme of Elementary (none as good as the original, though).

Comment: Why is this? Shouldn't regular GTK themes all work with Unity? Did Canonical mess with something to prevent this?